# NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am receiving a push notification and trying to parse the dictionary as follows but I am getting the following exception.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a6574ef8'

Here is my received dictionary

[image]

**Implementation**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
       // exception happens the following line
        if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] != NULL && 
           [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]isEqualToString:@"New Order!"])
        {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"newOrderNotificationMessage" object: [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]];
        }
}
```

Comment: your alert value is NSNULL class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need also check for `NSNull` class, try with this

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        // exception happens the following line
        if([[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] != NULL && [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] class] != [NSNull class]){
            if ([[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]isEqualToString:@"New Order!"])
            {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"newOrderNotificationMessage" object: [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"]];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778103/ordering-array-with-another-element