# ordering array with another array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following `categoryNames` array.

[image]

And now, I have `categoryTempElements` and it has `cName` property. I need to know how to order `categoryTempElements` with a order of `categoryNames`.

[image]

**UPDATE**: I have added `sortOrder` property to `Category` object and tried the following but order does not change.

```
for (Category* a in categoryTempElements) {
      int index = (int)[categoryNames indexOfObject:a.cName];
      a.sortOrder = index;
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortOrder" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [categoryTempElements sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: I need solution in objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first convert your `categoryNames` array into `dictionary` with `NSString` key and `NSNumber` `int` value, the value will be the order in the array

```
//this is example code, this will be your first array (reference value array)
NSArray * array = @[@"prueba",@"prueba2",@"prueba3"];
//first you need convert this array in NSDictionary

NSMutableDictionary * arrayDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
int counter = 0;
for (NSString * value in array) {
    if(arrayDict[value] == nil)
    {
        arrayDict[value] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:counter];
    }
    counter++;
}
```

After that then you can get the value and order with `sortedArrayUsingComparator` method, something like this

```
//this is an example of your second array categoryTempElements
NSArray * arrayOfObjs = @[[testObject testObjectWithName:@"prueba3"],[testObject testObjectWithName:@"prueba"],[testObject testObjectWithName:@"prueba2"]];

    NSArray * sorted = [arrayOfObjs sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(testObject *  _Nonnull obj1, testObject * _Nonnull obj2) {
        if([((NSNumber*)arrayDict[obj1.cName]) intValue] < [((NSNumber*)arrayDict[obj2.cName]) intValue]){
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        }

         if([((NSNumber*)arrayDict[obj1.cName]) intValue] > [((NSNumber*)arrayDict[obj2.cName]) intValue]){
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        }

        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];


    for (testObject * obj in sorted) {
         NSLog(@"%@",obj.cName);
    }
```

And voila in `sorted` you will have your array of object sorted by your first array `NSString` order

Hope this helps

Comment: Any idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808703/order-an-array-based-on-one-property

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be without using `sortedArrayUsingComparator`, using two for-loops.
 Declare a new Mutable array called `sortedCategoryElements` and compare the `categoryNames` in `categoryTempElements`, If matches add it to a new array `sortedCategoryElements`:

```
NSMutableArray *sortedCategoryElements = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSString *name in categoryNames) {
    for (Category *category in categoryTempElements) {
        if (name == category.cName) {
            [sortedCategoryElements addObject:category];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with your set of data, it worked for me. 
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with cName as the key and the Category object as the value. Then iterate over the categoryNames array, and build another array by using each item in categoryNames as the key. The resulting array should be sorted in the same order as categoryNames.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` has a method `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` which sorts an array using the ordering implemented by the block you pass. This block, of type `NSComparator`, is passed references to two elements of your array and you must return the order of those two elements.

> And now, I have `categoryTempElements` and it has cName property.

So your block will be passed two `categoryTempElements`, you need to access the `cName` property of each, and compare the resulting two values...

> I need to know how to order `categoryTempElements` with a order of `categoryNames`

by the position, i.e. the *index*, of those values in your `categoryNames` array. The method `indexOfObject:` provides that index for you.

So put that together and your problem is solved.

HTH

Comment: I have updated my question with the approach that you have suggested but I am getting the same order, ordering did not change.

Comment: This answer does not suggest you add any properties, or use sort descriptors - neither are required - and that is what your current edit shows. Read the documentation for the methods and types I mentioned, read the steps in the answer, and you'll have your solution in a few lines of code. If you get stuck you can edit your question, or ask a new one, showing what you've done and explaining what doesn't work. HTH