# Order an array based on one property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSMutableArray called `allItems` which has the following `ProductData` object.

Each object has `cid, cname, ctype` and `cimage`. As you see below json object is not coming in order. However, `cid` is a indicator for ordering.

I wonder how do you order based on cid?

```
 [
  {
    "cid": "2",
    "cname": "Meats",
    "ctype": "main",
    "cimage": "baked_chicken.jpg"
  },
  {
    "cid": "1",
    "cname": "Dips",
    "ctype": "side",
    "cimage": "stuffed_eggplant.jpg"
  },
  {
    "cid": "4",
    "cname": "Sandwiches",
    "ctype": "sand",
    "cimage": "chickenshawarma.jpg"
  },
  {
    "cid": "3",
    "cname": "Appetizers",
    "ctype": "side",
    "cimage": "rice_lentils.jpg"
  },
  {
    "cid": "5",
    "cname": "Desserts",
    "ctype": "dsrt",
    "cimage": "cake.jpg"
  }]
```

If I use the `sortDescriptior`, it partially works. The issue that I am facing, when it sorts, it first display `cid` 1 and then `cid` 10 and then `cid` 2.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cid" ascending:YES];
[allItems sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: You can use sortDescriptor for this

Comment: Please check my update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a sort descriptor with a comparator passing `compare:options:` and option `NSNumericSearch`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cid" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
     return [obj1 compare:obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
```

or even simpler:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cid" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

`localizedStandardCompare` is a special comparison selector:

> This method should be used whenever file names or other strings are presented in lists and tables where Finder-like sorting is appropriate. The exact sorting behavior of this method is different under different locales and may be changed in future releases. This method uses the current locale.

Comment: This is the best solution by far. Strings already know how to be sorted, if they contain numeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cid" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {

    if ([obj1 integerValue] > [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if ([obj1 integerValue] < [obj2 integerValue]) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];
sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[aSortDescriptor]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"cId" 
    ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

arrToBeSort = [arrToBeSort sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray 
    descriptor]];
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cid.intValue" ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Your "array" has now been sorted after print it

Printing description of array: <__NSArrayM 0x618000041bf0>( { cid = 1; cimage = "stuffed_eggplant.jpg"; cname = Dips; ctype = side; }, { cid = 2; cimage = "baked_chicken.jpg"; cname = Meats; ctype = main; }, { cid = 3; cimage = "rice_lentils.jpg"; cname = Appetizers; ctype = side; }, { cid = 4; cimage = "chickenshawarma.jpg"; cname = Sandwiches; ctype = sand; }, { cid = 5; cimage = "cake.jpg"; cname = Desserts; ctype = dsrt; } )

Comment: It partially works. The issue that I am facing, when it sorts, it first display `cid `1 and then `cid` 10 and then `cid` 2.

Comment: Check it and Print Array

Comment: @hotspring why it not work with you

Comment: @ AbdelahadDarwish It will not work when you have different type number like ones, tens,hundreds.It should be same type.

Comment: Just  add this  sortDescriptorWithKey:@"cid.intValue"

Comment: check again my solution and tell me the result